# How to data bind nested ListView ItemTemplates in Metro/WinRT?

Tags: c#, data-binding, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

In my ViewModel I have a collection of objects which each contain another collection. I am trying to display this in my View by using nested ListView ItemTemplates. Here is a simplification of my ViewModel code:

```
public ViewModelObject
{
    public ObservableCollection<OuterObject> OuterCollection { get; }
}

public OuterObject
{
    public string OuterTitle;
    public ObservableCollection<InnerObject> InnerCollection { get; }
}

public InnerObject
{
    public string InnerTitle;
}
```

And here is a simplification of how I'm trying to use this ViewModel in my XAML:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding OuterCollection}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding OuterTitle}"/>
                <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding InnerCollection}">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding InnerTitle}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

If I remove the inner ListView, the outer ListView binding works perfectly fine. I just can't figure out how to properly bind the inner collection object to the inner ListView. I've tried doing the inner binding with `{Binding OuterCollection.InnerCollection}`, `{Binding DataContext.InnerCollection}`, and `{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=InnerCollection}`, but all of these cause it to crash. What is the proper way to achieve this nested binding?

**EDIT:** I should add that this is for an application being ported from Windows Phone 7, and it is an attempt to find a replacement for `LongListSelector`, which is not available in WinRT.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I figured out the solution! It required a combination of my previously attempted solutions. The correct binding for the internal collection in a nested ListView is:

```
{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},
                         Path=DataContext.InnerCollection}
```

Also, depending on your purpose for the nested ListViews, I found it better to use an ItemsView for the outer collection and a ListView for the inner collection. Otherwise, the selectability of the two controls overlap each other.

Comment: This worked for me! I went crazy trying to figure it out. One issue -- did you have to change the {Binding InnerTitle} to something else? I'm seeing all my ListView elements correctly created, but {Binding InnerTitle} isn't working.

Comment: Nevermind -- my issue was that I didn't realize `public string Name;` doesn't bind, while `public string Name { get; set; }` does.